# How to prove an integral that is exactly half of another integral exists?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

Given that f is integrable, find a "c" such that the integral from a to c is exactly half of the integral from a to b.

That is $\int_{a}^{c}fdx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}f dx$

now we have to show that $c\in(a,b).$

We just learned the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions, but I'm not too sure how to use that here (or if we're even supposed to). We can't use much cool stuff beyond the IVT, basic integral properties, and real number analysis (no differentiation).

Comment: The question is embedded in the picture link 1

Comment: Hi need. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: try thinking about it graphically...

Comment: The Intermediate Value Theorem is a good approach.  You need to establish continuity with respect to the upper limit of integration, which gives you a chance to use another "fundamental" result.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Define $g(t)=\int_a^t f(s)\, ds$.

- Verify that $g$ is continuous.
- Evaluate $g(a)$.
- Evaluate $g(b)$.

Comment: How do you show that g is continuous? It's not always true that an integrated function is continuous right?

Comment: What does integrable mean to you?

Comment: Riemann integrable (upper and lower integrals are the same).

Comment: You might like to use $f$ is bounded and squeeze theorem to prove continuity.

Comment: I've proven that g(t) is integrable. How do I find a "c" such that g(c) - g(a) = 1/2 (∫())

Comment: you don't find it explicitly, use intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now :)